# Is it possible to disable CPU throttling on a MacBook Pro with a completely dead (not recognized) battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, performance, cpu

I have a MBP late 2011 running El Capitan, recently my battery died (x over the icon and "no battery available" in the dropdown.) I've noticed since then that CPU intensive tasks are very slow, and I read that without a battery macs will throttle the CPU to half capacity.

So now I'm looking for one of two solutions:

1) Either somehow disable the throttling, or 
2) Trick the computer into thinking it has a battery.

In regard to the first one I've tried a few things such as described [here](http://www.rdoxenham.com/?p=259), removing a plist file that supposedly controlled it, but that hasn't helped. Any help would be greatly appreciated, TIA.

Edit: I've looked over the question about a 2006 MacBook, it's similar but I've tried everything outlined there and nothing has worked. I'm curious if there are any new ideas. I think the difference may be El Capitan.

Comment: That explains a lot.. I have an (8GB RAM) i7 MBP-Retina; plugged in all the time because the battery is totally dead. It used to be such a beast, now it seems to struggle with.. pretty much everything..

Comment: Guess option 1 is not achievable. Read more here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41045/how-can-i-disable-cpu-throttling-and-cpu-disabling#41069

Answer (score 3):

Not practically. You're better off selling the computer for parts or getting a replacement battery / having the Mac serviced by a professional.

Non user replaceable batteries are very vulnerable to damage and lithium battery fires are no joke. Even global companies have struggled with making safe products from brand new parts (galaxy 7) so please don't cut corners on safety when Apple batteries are involved - especially with repair parts or unauthorized / uninsured repair shops.

Several people have [tried disabling kernel extensions and tried to patch the firmware](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/380493/5472) to varying levels of “success” and “this may damage your Mac permanently” comfort.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/jakwings/GoodbyeBigSlow.kext) is my solution (disable aggressive throttling) and I'm the developer.  I don't have to do something more dangerous as instructed in [this article](https://grafxflow.co.uk/blog/mac-os-x/delete-ioplatformpluginfamilykext-macos-big-sur).  CPU/GPU will be throttled again after wake-up from system sleep/hibernation or when it becomes really hot (seems so).  There is a kernel extension compiled for [OSX 10.11](https://github.com/jakwings/GoodbyeBigSlow.kext/releases/download/Downloads/GoodbyeBigSlow-v2022.2.7.zip).  NO WARRANTY!