# MacBook Pro lags when at 0% and charging

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, battery, charging

I have a 2010 MacBook Pro with 256GB SSD and 8GB RAM.

However, it lags horribly when it's down to 0% - even when connected to the power source. Also, it takes over half an hour to get to 1% - then, it starts charging at an adequate speed.

Additionally, it won't get to the 1% at all when it's on. It has to be sleeping or off.

It's been doing this even *before* it became obsolete (in June 2017).

Why is my MacBook doing this? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known/expected behavior as the processor lags noticeably when the battery is removed on any recent MacBook to MacBook Pro. If you can avoid getting the battery below 10% or replace the battery - all normal performance should resume.

- [Is it possible to disable CPU throttling on a MacBook Pro with a completely dead (not recognized) battery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220929/)
- [How to disable the SpeedStep when using MacBook Pro without a battery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116193/)