# Extremely low system speed

Tags: install, hardware, performance

I have a MacBook Pro 13" Early 2015. Recently, my keyboard has broken. It first reported spurious hits, then after a few days nothing, so the computer was usable only with an external keyboard. While transferring all my data to another computer, I noticed that the speed of the system has much decreased. I wondered if I want the computer repaired, but with that low speed, this makes no sense. I decided to completely erase the SSD and reinstall MacOS, which I did following https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496. But even in recovery mode's disk utility and MacOS setup, I noticed how slow the computer reacts (e.g., when it shows window animations). Where can this come from?

Note on the battery: some might suspect the battery has bloated. Therefore, I took out the battery and checked if the keyboard works without battery inserted, which is not the case. As of now, there is no battery inside.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the battery from intel based MacBooks [slows the processor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/220929/5472). To regain full speed, place a repaired battery in the Mac and run diagnostics to ensure the system is repaired and without fault.

Comment: [if you are comfortable with a potential fire or permanent damage, you might enjoy trying to modify the protections on the hardware.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/380493/5472)

Comment: I guess there's no reliable way around that? Basically, I only want to assess the performance of the notebook *before* I do the invest into the repair.